# Regular Expression to accept only alphabets in the 1st place of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text field that should only accept alphabets, hyphen, space, and apostrophe. Also it should only accept hyphen, space, and apostrophe with at least 1 alphabet at start.

I have tried this:

```
var testExp = new RegExp("[a-z' -]","gi");
```

This is allowing alphabets, hyphen, space, and apostrophe at any place. I need help restricting hyphen, space, and apostrophe at start of the string.

Example:

Test-abc should accept

-abc Should not accept

Comment: Try it like this `^[a-z][a-z' -]*`

Answer (score 0):

`\A[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\'\s\-]+\Z`

`\A` Indicates the start of the string

`[A-Za-z]` Indicates the expression starting with letters uppercase or lowercase.

`[A-Za-z\'\s\-]+`  The plus(+) means 1 or more \s is space \- is hyphen and \' is apostrophe.
`\Z` is the end of the string.

Combined they should help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `var testExp = new RegExp("^[a-z][a-z' -]*$","gi");` should work.
`^` is to notate the start of the string while `$` is to notate the end of the string.
So `^[a-z]` tests that there is a alphabetical character in the start,
 and `[a-z' -]*$"` tests that the rest of the string is comprised of the allowed characters.

Comment: I have tried this too. Its not allowing hyphen, space, and apostrophe at all anywhere in the string, not only at the start.

Comment: Try `/^[a-z][a-z' -]*$/i.test('Test-abc')` for some reason I also got odd results when I was using the 'g' modifier, but this works.
Also [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is a great resource to test your regular expressions.

Comment: @anubhava I do believe that is exactly what @Techno wanted was for it to not match `-abc`

Comment: Yes I know but OP wrote `Its not allowing hyphen, space, and apostrophe at all anywhere in the string` which doesn't appear correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
var testExp = new RegExp("^[a-z][a-z' -]*","gi");
```

the `^` sign will force the occurance to happen from the start of the string.
read more here (you have a lot of control over what you want to extract or validate):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

Comment: I have tried this. its not allowing hyphen, space, and apostrophe at all anywhere in the string.

Comment: You may do something wrong, check here, the regex just works: https://regex101.com/r/W0Jkbz/1

Answer (score 0):

See for a full explanation and test: https://regex101.com/r/5xmC0j/1

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-'\s]+$
```